# Background image showing through picture with transparent background

Tags: css, seo, transparency, opacity, png-transparency

I'm trying to create a banner for a website.  For SEO purposes, I decided to see if I could create the banner in type rather than as an imported image.  I'm making good progress, but for some reason my background image is showing through a logo overlaid on top of it.

I have the background image (set in css) set with opacity because I don't want it full strength.  Over it I place the logo which has a transparent background, but no opacity.

The goal banner is at:

http://arielbalter.com/cio/

The code I'm trying is at:

http://jsfiddle.net/abalter/QzNpQ/

*****   HTML   ***********

```
<header>
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="background-image"></div>
        <div id="logo">
            <img id="house-logo" src="http://arielbalter.com/cio/img/CheckItOutHouseNoBackground.png" />
    </div>
        <div id="lines">
            <h1 id="line1">check it out!</h1>
            <h1 id="line2">Home Inspection</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

**  CSS  **********

```
header {
    border: 3px double black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 7em;
}
#outer {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
#background-image {
    background-image: url("http://arielbalter.com/cio/img/3tab_slanted.jpg");
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
#logo {
    float: left;
    border: 1px dashed green;
    height: 100%;
}
#logo img {
    height: 100%;
}
#lines {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px dotted blue;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
#line1 {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    font-family:"KGLoveSomebody", "Comic Sans MS", sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3em;
    color: FireBrick;
    padding: 0.1em 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 -0.4em 0;
    border: 2px dashed green;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}
#line2 {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    font-family:"Trebuchet", sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    border: 2px dashed orange;
    font-variant: small-caps;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: your JSfiddle is blank

Comment: No code at your fiddle, and it's not clear from the first link what "banner" you're referring to, and what the issue actually is?

Comment: @abalter: Please fill your fiddle so we can help you

Comment: I'm totally sorry about the jsfiddle!  The only think I can think of is that I forgot to save it.  AND there is no code under HTML.  Major foul.

This must be it:

http://jsfiddle.net/abalter/f68xn/1/

I was able to use relative and absolute to fix it.

http://jsfiddle.net/abalter/F7wx6/

Everntually, instead of using a background with an image on top of it, I am using two images so they both scale.

Sorry again.

Comment: HTML code wasn't showing up because I didn't format it as code.  Sorry again.  I edited the post to fix it.

Comment: I was able to use relative and absolute to fix it.  I positioned the background image as absolute and the logo as relative.  Should I post the answer to my own question: "Answer Your Question"?

Answer (score 3):

**Diagnosis:**

From what I understand based on your CSS, the opacity on `#background-image` is affecting the opacity of `#logo`.

**Solution 1:**

If it's possible, instead of a photo, consider using a background color for parent element with `background-color: rgba(x,y,z,a)` where the number `a` is responsible for opacity.

**Solution 2:**

If you want to use two images on top eachother with only parent element having an opacity,  `position absolute` will help you to display them in seperate divs without any opacity problem.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that logo is ending up behind the background image.  I think that is very strange since the background-image is in it's own div, and comes before the logo in the html.

The logo image is in it's own div (<div id="logo").  However, if I add position: absolute, the logo is on top, but the text floats over the logo!

Is there a fix for that?